# Use a referential table to filter data

Tags: sql, business-intelligence

I'm working on a project for which I would like to allow an end-user to create dynamic "filters" to apply on a fact table, by filling a referential table.

Let say I have this fact table:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| Key  | AttrA | AttrB | AttrC |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| Key1 | Text1 | Text2 | Text3 |
| Key2 | Txt1  | Txt2  | Txt3  |
| Key3 | Text1 | Text2 | Text3 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The effects of filters can be:

- Attribute = 'Text'
- Attribute like '%Text%'
- Attribute <> 'Text'
- Attribute not like '%Text%'

Also, "negative" filters (<> and not like) can be cumulative.

What kind of referential table can I create, and how can I apply these conditions within a sql statement?

I thought of a referential table like:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Filter  | TypeA | AttrA | TypeB | AttrB | TypeC | AttrC |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Filter1 | =     | Text1 |       |       |       |       |
| Filter2 |       |       | <>    | Text2 |       |       |
| Filter2 |       |       | <>    | Text3 |       |       |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I need to associate the Filter value to Fact table lines.
So I can do:

```
Select Key, Filter from FactTable Fa
Inner Join FilterTable Fi on Fi.TypeA = '=' and Fi.TypeB = '=' and Fi.TypeC         = '=' and Fa.AttrA = Fi.AttrA and Fa.AttrB = Fi.AttrB and Fa.AttrC = Fi.AttrC
```

And

```
Select Key, Filter from FactTable Fa
Inner Join FilterTable Fi on Fi.TypeA = '=' and Fi.TypeB = '=' and Fi.TypeC = '<>' and Fa.AttrA = Fi.AttrA and Fa.AttrB = Fi.AttrB and Fa.AttrC <> Fi.AttrC
```

But I would need to manage each case for each attribute (I have more than 3 attributes), meaning 4^NbColumns requests, and I don't see how to do for cumulative negative conditions.

Anyone has an idea how to do such a thing?
If needed, I have an SSIS I can use (if package or C# script can help).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to find an easier way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Any clue how to?
I only have SQL Server and SSIS with me. Referential table structure can be modified.